# What does the word "but" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is our view that the Assembly has the authority to decline
to accept findings of the Tribunal and has also the unquestionable authority to accept
the findings of the Tribunal **but** to vary the awards the Tribunal has made.

Comment: It seems to me, it's a usual conjunction which is "used to introduce something contrasting with what has already been mentioned." You can replace it with "however". The Assembly can accept the finding, *however* it can vary the awards (despite the fact of acceptance of the findings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the tribunal has established "findings" with associated awards. The Assembly reserves the right to accept the findings except as to the amount of the awards, which it will establish.
Here, I've used the word "except" as a synonym of "but". These words mean that what follows them is at odds with what came before: we accept the findings; we do not accept the amount of the awards.